# Windows Dynamic DNS Update Sequence

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dhcp

I'm trying to get the Windows DDNS update sequence straight in my head. Here's what I think happens:

```
Windows Client             == DHCP Discover
Windows DHCP Server        == DHCP Offer
Windows Client             == DHCP Request with option 81
                              {Client is requesting DHCP server to register reverse 
                              PTR record and offering to register its own A record}
Windows DHCP Server        == DHCP Acknowledge with option 81
                              {Server agrees and updates the client's PTR record on 
                              the DNS server}
Windows Client             == DHCP client updates A record on DNS server.
```

What happens when the DHCP server is configured to register DNS A records on the client's behalf whether the client requests this or not? Does the client still attempt to update the DNS server directly?

Comment: What version of Windows? The process has changed slightly between 2000/2003/XP and 2008+.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know how it's changed actually, so lets say WinXP/7/8.